# How can I add elements to a JSON array without adding "?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm developing a library with C#, .NET Framework 4.0 and Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.8.

I'm trying to create my own serializer:

```
public static string Serialize(List<Models.Codes> codes)
{
    if (codes == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("codes");
    if (codes.Count == 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("codes");

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw);

    writer.WriteStartArray();
    foreach (Models.Codes code in codes)
        writer.WriteValue(CodesSerializer.Serialize(code));

    writer.WriteEndArray();

    return sw.ToString();
}

public static string Serialize(Models.Codes code)
{
    if (code == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("code");

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw);

    writer.WriteStartObject();

    writer.WritePropertyName("Code");
    writer.WriteValue(code.Code);

    writer.WritePropertyName("BatchId");
    writer.WriteValue(code.BatchId);

    writer.WritePropertyName("ProductId");
    writer.WriteValue(code.ProductId);

    writer.WritePropertyName("CodeLevel");
    writer.WriteValue(code.CodeLevel);

    writer.WritePropertyName("CommisioningFlag");
    writer.WriteValue(code.CommisioningFlag);

    writer.WritePropertyName("Timespan");
    writer.WriteValue(code.Timespan);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code.Username))
    {
        writer.WritePropertyName("Username");
        writer.WriteValue(code.Username);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code.Source))
    {
        writer.WritePropertyName("Source");
        writer.WriteValue(code.Source);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code.Reason))
    {
        writer.WritePropertyName("Reason");
        writer.WriteValue(code.Reason);
    }

    writer.WriteEndObject();

    string text = sw.ToString();

    return text;
}
```

But it generates a string like this:

```
[\"{\\\"Code\\\":\\\"81861400008000002386\\\",\\\"BatchId\\\":5,\\\"ProductId\\\":7,\\\"CodeLevel\\\":1,\\\"CommisioningFlag\\\":1,\\\"Timespan\\\":null}\",
```

Have you notices the extra " before {?

How can I don't put that "?

I think the problem is that I am adding a value to an array inside the loop:

```
    writer.WriteStartArray();
    foreach (Models.Codes code in codes)
        writer.WriteValue(CodesSerializer.Serialize(code));

    writer.WriteEndArray();
```

I have changed `writer.WriteValue(CodesSerializer.Serialize(code));` with `writer.WriteRaw(CodesSerializer.Serialize(code));` and now it doesn't write ", but now I need to write JSON value delimiter and I can't use `writer.WriteValueDelimiter();`.

How can I add elements to a JSON array without adding "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I have to use `writer.WriteRawValue()`:

```
writer.WriteStartArray();
foreach (Models.Codes code in codes)
    writer.WriteRawValue(CodesSerializer.Serialize(code));

writer.WriteEndArray();
```